# Is the Infernal Machine Rebuild module allowed in Adventurers League?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, dnd-adventurers-league

My friend wants to learn to play in D&D Adventurers League, so I want to give him a Tier 1 adventure. I found this adventure called [*Infernal Machine Rebuild*](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/294711/Infernal-Machine-Rebuild-5e). I read the story and I like it.

But is it an AL-legal adventure? If so, what is its code?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, it's not AL-legal.

The ALCC, or Adventurers League Content Catalogue (available for free as part of the [D&D Adventurers League Player & DM Pack](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Players-Pack)) has the following to say about [*Infernal Machine Rebuild*](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/294711/Infernal-Machine-Rebuild-5e) on p. 13 (as of version 9.02) of the document:

> #### Infernal Machine Rebuild
>
> While *Infernal Machine Rebuild* is not an AL-legal adventure, those who
> complete it can apply the rewards from the included certificate to one
> of their Adventurers League characters.

Comment: I'm not a *5e* player, but unless the implications of that quotation will be universally understood by a newcomer, it may be worth explaining what that quotation means. (I mean, the quotation makes it sound like a player still gets an AL-applicable benefit for his PC for having completed the adventure, but I don't know what it would mean instead if the adventure *were* AL-legal.)

Comment: Hmm. so. It cant be an legal adventure but still can get the Magic Item from the adventure aslong as you have your AL chara?

Comment: Yep, that's right.

Comment: (Just updating the answer with the above comment exchange would earn this answer my upvote.)